# Библиотека аннотаций Spring

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, аннотации

Начал изучать Spring и начинаю понимать, чтобы хорошо писать надо разобраться в кишках Spring. На данный момент проблема с аннотациями. Их очень много и не всегда понятно для чего они, и как работают. 
Есть ли какая-нибудь библиотека всех аннотаций Spring?

Comment: не пытайтесь понять все аннотации сразу. там очень много сильно специфичных.

Comment: Spring Framework на сегодняшний день - это зонтичный проект. В нем много подпроектов, каждый из которых предлагает свои аннотации. Чтобы понять как они работают, нужно читать документацию на соответствующий подпроект. У Spring документация весьма неплоха.

Comment: Еще есть обзорный RefCard от DZone: https://dzone.com/refcardz/spring-annotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел вот такое spring-annotations. Вроде похоже на правду.